# $T^TB T$ is still diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

> proposition: $T^TB T$ is diagonal, if $T$ is not orthogonal, then we orthogonalize $T$, and $T$ becomes $T1$, then $T1^TB T1$ is still diagonal

Is it right, when it's right?

$T$ is transpose

Comment: To integer:  how do we orthogonalize $T$?

Comment: If $T^T B T$ is diagonal, then $T^T B T$ is diagonal. Could you state more carefully what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

In general not: you have to orthogonalize the eigenvectors of each eigenspace separately.